# python player movement for game in 5x5 board

Tags: python

```
def playerMove (board,player):
userInput = input("Enter a direction NSWE: ").upper()
if userInput == "N":
    if (player == 0):
        board[player] = '.'
        player += 1
        board[player] = '@'
elif userInput == "S":

    if (player(board)-1):
        board[player] = '.'
        player += 1
        board[player] = '@'
elif userInput == "E":

    if (player < len(board)-1):
        board[player] = '.'
        player += 1
        board[player] = '@'
elif userInput == "W":

    if (player['x'] > 0):
        board[player] = '.'
        player -= 1
        board[player] = '@'
```

this is a sample coding for a game i am creating, i have everything already coded for when a player is created it is randomly placed on a 5x5 board. i need an option for a user to move the player NESW, but i cannot figure it out. this is not all of my coding, just the part that i need help with.

here is the board coding

```
'def createBoard():
tempList = []
for i in range (5):
    tempList.append(".")

board = []
for i in range (5):
    board.append(["."]*5)

return board


def showBoard(board):    
    print ("---------")
    print ("|".join(board[0]))
    print ("---------")
    print("|".join(board[1]))
    print ("---------")
    print("|".join(board[2]))
    print ("---------")
    print("|".join(board[3]))
    print ("---------")
    print("|".join(board[4]))
    print ("---------")

def placePlayer(board,player):
    len(board[0])
    row = random.randint(0, len(board) -1)
    col = random.randint(0, len(board[0])-1)
    board[row][col] = '@' 
    return board, row, col
```

Comment: it would be helpful to know what board and player are.  The answer will change greatly if you are using a single dimensional array vs a multidimensional array.

Comment: i will edit the post and show the board, the player is randomly generated though.

Comment: That doesn't address the content of my original question.  Is player an integer that represents the location on the board?  Is the board a single dimensional array or a Multidimensional array?  We cannot help answer the question if we do not know how the variables are setup and used

Comment: If player is an integer what is this supposed to do: `player(board)`? Perhaps what you want is a tuple representing the x,y coordinates of the player.

Comment: my instructor never mentioned a tuple :( idk what to do or how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Your player doesn't appear to be referenced by a single integer value, but instead a row and a col

You should update your code to either pass a tuple around or pass in the row and col values as in the following snippet:

```
def playerMove (board,playerRow, playerCol):
    if userInput == "N":
        if (playerRow > 0):
            board[playerRow][playerCol] = '.'
            playerRow -= 1
            board[playerRow][playerCol] = '@'
```

Note:  The above code assumes that your board is split into a multidimsional array.  As it is currently, you would need to manipulate the strings in your array as strings do not allow you to directly modify the contents in place.

Answer (score 0):

**1)**
First of all, in your board generating code you put:

```
board = []
for i in range (5):
    board.append(["."]*5)

return board
```

In that code, it is not necessary to use `return board` as it is not in a function.  Return statements are mostly used in functions:

```
def square(x):
    return x*x
```

**2)** Your board will be organized with a list in a list like the following:

```
board = [
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
    ]
```

To look up a point on the board you would use the following syntax:

```
board[row][col]
```

The `[row]` points to the list in the board list, while the `[col]` points to an item in that list.  So to find a point on the grid you need both the row and the column.

To move the player up one in the board you would use the following:

```
board[row][col] = '.' #reset last position to '.'
board[row][col-1] = '@' #set the coordinate above to '@'
```

And to move the player one to the right you would use the following:

```
board[row][col] = '.' #reset last position '.'
board[row+1][col] = '@' #set the coordinate to the right to '@'
```